# Sonar update 5.0.1 to 5.1: "Can not render widget measure_filter_list" on "Projects" dashboard

Tags: sonarqube

After successfully running the database upgrade during installation of the Sonar upgrade from 5.0.1 to 5.1, the homepage ("Projects" dashboard) displays an error message.

In the log file I see the following "Ruby on Rails" (?) stacktrace:

```
2016.01.28 14:25:35 ERROR web[rails] Can not render widget measure_filter_list: 
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass) on line #207 of app/views/measures/_display_list.html.erb:
204:       <% end %>
205:       <% filter.display.columns.each do |column| %>
206:         <td class="<%= column.align -%> <%= column.row_css -%>">
207:           <%= list_cell_html(column, row) -%>
208:         </td>
209:       <% end %>
210:     </tr>

    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:118:in `human_short_date'
    app/helpers/measures_helper.rb:57:in `list_cell_html'
    app/views/measures/_display_list.html.erb:207
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    app/views/measures/_display_list.html.erb:205
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    app/views/measures/_display_list.html.erb:200
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
    compiled-template:18:in `_run_inline_531921568_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:269:in `render'
    app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:162:in `widget_body'
    app/views/dashboard/_widget.html.erb:3
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
    app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:19
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:15
    org/jruby/RubyRange.java:427:in `each'
    app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:9
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
    file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
    file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Also, the "Time Machine" dashboard of all my existing projects are completely broken with a similar message:

```
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails] Can not render widget time_machine: undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   compiled-template:80:in `_run_inline_733135258_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   compiled-template:76:in `_run_inline_733135258_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:269:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:162:in `widget_body'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/_widget.html.erb:3:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47_widget46html46erb_locals_object_widget'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:19:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:15:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyRange.java:427:in `each'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:9:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   jar:file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   jar:file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   /opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
2016.01.28 14:35:30 ERROR web[rails]   file:/opt/tools/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

From what I can see in the database migration log output, a lot of "date" named columns have been renamed and/or removed from the database - somehow this seems to be related.

We are running SonarQube on a Linux box in an Oracle XE database. We want to upgrade to Sonar 5.3 in order to use some newer plugins. As we have some history for our projects, we do not want to lose it...

Are there some other pre-requisites not mentioned in the Upgrade guide of SonarQube (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading and http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.1+Upgrade+Notes) that I need to fulfil?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading, you have to analysis your projects once the upgrade is finished to have fresh data.
Is it a step you performed ?

Comment: I did not dare - I was afraid of losing all historic data...
Do you really suggest to try this? Maybe I give it a shot when I get the time again...