# Sonar update to 5.4 cannot display project list

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

Upgraded SonarQube to 5.4 with an oracle 12c database back end. Upgrade went exactly as the steps in the documentation outlines and with no errors.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading

On the project list screen I get the following error:

An error occurred while trying to display the widget "measure_filter_list". Please contact the administrator.

This is identical to the following issue rasied previously for 5.1 only the solution here has not resolved my issue. I have re-ran analysis and can view that in Sonar but still the list screen does not work.

[Sonar update 5.0.1 to 5.1: "Can not render widget measure_filter_list" on "Projects" dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127627/sonar-update-5-0-1-to-5-1-can-not-render-widget-measure-filter-list-on-proje)

The following is the extract from the sonar.log:

```
2016.03.25 11:57:42 ERROR web[rails] Can not render widget measure_filter_list:
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass) on line #208 of app/views/measures/_display_list.html.erb:
   <% end %>
   <% filter.display.columns.each do |column| %>
     <td class="<%= column.align -%> <%= column.row_css -%>">
       <%= list_cell_html(column, row) -%>
     </td>
   <% end %>
 </tr>

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:118:in `human_short_date'
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried creating a new list?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found out what the issue was.

On initial install the person who set it up used the oracle 12.1.0.1 driver. Switched to the 11g driver and we are working away.